# Setting document.documentElement.clientWidth to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show more/less list items depending on the screen size. I want this to work on load and as the page is resized manually.

It works fine if I directly use $(document).innerWidth() or document.documentElement.clientWidth, but if I set either of those to a variable and try to use that instead, it stops working. What gives?

```
// Doesn't work
var getWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if (getWidth <= 559) {
    // hide some list items
}

// Works
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 559) {
    // hide some list items
}
```

Here is a jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/midice/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for this. Use CSS media queries instead.

Comment: Just from your JSBin, I noticed that if the width is above 559 when the page is started, then it shows three items in the bottom list.  My guess is that the code to set the variable is only run one time, assigning the variable to whatever the value is at the time.  `document.documentElement.clientWidth` updates in real time, but the variable doesn't.

Comment: I also need to add a "See More" link and toggle visibility on the hidden list items. This is just a paired example for the problem I'm having.

Comment: you can reveal your link and toggle anything using CSS.

Comment: Still probably viable. A CSS-only example of the current JSBin behavior: http://jsbin.com/tayepakuqo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: don't use/trust those reported values; they won't work correctly with mobile or zoom; use CSS instead.

Comment: Ah! You are right @alexafroscia. I need the variable in a function outside the resize event as well though, is it ok to just duplicate it?

Comment: This fixes your issue, but I'd still use media queries. http://jsbin.com/wafapacudi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You're all correct. I can do much of this with CSS, but the sole purpose of the link is to toggle visibility of the hidden list items. I'm sure I can do that with some sort of checkbox hack, but I'm not really comfortable doing that. I'm trying to use progressive enhancement so I don't want the list items to be hidden unless the JS functionality to show and hide is available. Unless I am totally missing some obvious way to do that with CSS.

Comment: @Dave Gillhespy just define a function that you call on page load and on window resize.